# Django-Celery Periodic tasks error handling

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Celery task that takes no argument that runs periodically in the background.

I want to use `on_failure` to traceback on the error for the particular object it encounters.

Since it doesn't takes any argument I am not able to assign the value to `args`.

How should I get the object and the error it encounters while the task is getting executed?

Comment: if you add your code snippet, your question will be clearer

Answer (score 0):

I guess this piece of code is working

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask
class Task(PeriodicTask):
     run_every = crontab(minute=0, hour=0)
     def run(self, **kwargs):
         # to do
     def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
         print("Failed")
```